# Is there a way to draw matplotlib plots to a window in some other 2D rendering library?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The idea would be that you'd have some 2D library for your GUI like PyGame and then draw the plots into the window generated by the library instead of an independent window generated by matplotlib. Allowing for user input and plot viewing in the same window.

I don't have any specific 2D library in mind, I'm not super familiar with Python libraries.

The only way I could find is by saving the plots to a file and then rendering that, but that seems extremely costly for real-time rendering (which is what I'm considering).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed a plot from matplotlib into a `tkinter` app, check out their documentation here!

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html

Tkinter is a built-in package with cross platform support.